# Schengen Visa - want to visit different country

Tags: schengen

Im a resident of the UK but hold a non-UK passport. I hope you are somehow aware about the issue with the lack of visa appointments here in UK. It's just impossible to book an appointment to almost any Schengen country. I just got lucky with my slot for Netherlands.

If I only have a choice, I will apply my visa to the country that I really want to visit primarily. I don't want to bend any rules or find any loopholes, but due to the VFS situation, I am desperate here.

I really want to visit France, not Netherlands. Now, what if I book roundtrip flights from UK to Amsterdam. Then once in Amsterdam, get a train/plane to France and spend majority of my trip there. At the end of the trip, go back to Amsterdam for my exit. What are the risks here? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Are you proposing to submit a made-up itinerary and accommodation reservations in NL to justify applying to NL instead of France? Split your trip 55/45 in favour of NL and you can do this without breaking any rules or risking being caught through eg random border checks, verification of accommodation reservations

Comment: @Traveller Thank you so much for answering. I was just trying to exhaust the fact that flights within the area are 'domestic', but I think I get the picture now. Splitting the trip as you suggested is a good and safe idea.

Answer (score 4):

There would be two options:

- You **tell the truth** in the description of the itinerary, and the Netherlands will decline to process your application because you *should* be applying in France.
- You **lie** in the description of the itinerary. Either this deception is not detected, and you may get the visa, or it is detected because your bogus plans appear incoherent. Then your visa application would be denied and that gets into your record.

While you may not be caught, it is a really bad idea to take the risk.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Either I go all in for Amsterdam, or I split the trip equally. I guess I was just trying to understand what is it like when I get there. For example, if I get on the train, what checks are thy going to do?

Comment: @j08, internal Schengen borders are mostly open and most trains have no security check-in. But temporary checks can be reintroduced, and France currently has several in place.

Comment: @j08 but I doubt that internal border checks are going to expose you.  If anything does, it's more likely to be a follow-up investigation on your accommodation.